# no content after POST request

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to scrape this website: https://ssweb.seap.minhap.es/portalEELL/consulta_alcaldes

When you choose Alicante from the first menu and then Ayuntamiento de Abengibre from the second you will see a table with results. This is what I want.

I saw in Chrome Console that choosing the values in drop-downs generates a POST request. So I thought it would be straight-forward to obtain that with `requests.post`

```
params = {
    "consulta_alcalde[_csrf_token]":"dd1546dd35bf0f1af4a1f3aac165a1b5",
    "consulta_alcalde[id_provincia]":"2",
    "consulta_alcalde[id_entidad]":"17926"  
    }


r = requests.post("https://ssweb.seap.minhap.es/portalEELL/consulta_alcaldes", params)
```

But then when I check what r.text contains I get 200 response but can't see my data from the table. What am I doing wrong?

I am aware it can be done with Selenium but I am trying to avoid it as it's very slow.

EDIT:

As per Brian's suggestion I have modified my code as:

```
params = {
   "consulta_alcalde[_csrf_token]":"dd1546dd35bf0f1af4a1f3aac165a1b5",
   "consulta_alcalde[id_provincia]":"2",
   "consulta_alcalde[id_entidad]":"17951",
   "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"
   }

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.get("https://ssweb.seap.minhap.es/portalEELL/consulta_alcaldes")
    r = s.post("https://ssweb.seap.minhap.es/portalEELL/consulta_alcaldes", data=params)
```

But still no luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "csrf_token" is not static, you'll have to parse the page with `bs4` to get it.
Also the site provides content via xhr request, so you need to have "XMLHttpRequest" in the headers.  Code:

```
url = 'https://ssweb.seap.minhap.es/portalEELL/consulta_alcaldes'
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(url, verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
csrf_token = soup.find('input', id="consulta_alcalde__csrf_token")['value']
data = {
    "consulta_alcalde[_csrf_token]":csrf_token,
    "consulta_alcalde[id_provincia]":"2",
    "consulta_alcalde[id_entidad]":"17951"
}
headers = {"X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest"}
r = s.post(url, data=data, headers=headers, verify=False)
print(r.content)
```

Comment: This is the solution I needed! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

With a post request, the payload should be the body of the request.  To do this make pass the params using the data keyword argument.

```
requests.post(url, data=payload)
```

If the post requires json, then you can either use `json.dumps` or simply pass the payload to the json keyword argument instead.

```
requests.post(url, json=payload)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this gives the same result. as randomir suggests above I might be missing some authentication parameter. Thanks

Comment: Does the site require authentication (e.g. a username/password)? Secondly, if its just a matter of session cookies, use a requests Session and do a `session.get` to the primary URL (this will populate all the session headers, etc) followed by your `session.post`.

Comment: Also consider using a User-Agent header other than the default, usually emulating a browser User-Agent works well.

Comment: no it soesn't require authentication. it's a good idea to try with Session.